# Redirect links on a webpage to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to redirect links on a web page and in this simple example, it just goes through a simple check for a cookie to be set.

Not sure if that's the right way to take care of this situation in the first place, and if I am going to run into problem when there are several links with the "download_link" class, but even right now, with only one of such link, the destination is set to undefined, it looks like the $(this) in the call to redirector is actually pointing the the whole HTML document instead of just the element I am trying to change...

```
    function redirect_link(e, destination) {
        if ($.cookie("contact_set") == "true") {
            window.location.href = destination;
        } else {
            alert("cookie not set");
        }
    }
    function redirector(destination) {
        alert("creating redirector to "+destination);
        return function(e) {redirect_link(e, destination)};
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.download_link').click(redirector($(this).attr("href")));
        $('.download_link').attr("href", "#");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing `$(this)` from the scope of document's `ready` callback, so `$this` points to a `HTMLDocument` object!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $downloadLnk = $('.download_link');
    $downloadLnk.click(redirector($downloadLnk.attr("href")));
    $downloadLnk.attr("href", "#");
});
```

As you requested it in your comment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.download_link').each(function() {
    var $lnk = $(this);
    $lnk.click(redirector($lnk.attr("href")));
    $lnk.attr("href", "#");
  });
});
```

Comment: That seems to work well for now while I only have one of such link.... what do I do to handle more links?

Comment: If you can identify each link with a selector, you can use jQuery's `each` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() { // <-- Short for $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.download_link').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.click(redirector($this.attr("href"));
        $this.attr("href", "#");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the target :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.download_link').on('click', redirector); //bind to function
    $('.download_link').attr("href", "#");
});​

function redirector(event) {
    alert("creating redirector to "+event.target.href); //event.target
    return function(e) {redirect_link(e, destination)};
}
```

But by the time your link is clicked the href will be `#` no matter what you use, as you set it to that value on the next line after the click handler ?

Comment: wouldn't the href already be reset to "#" by the time it gets into redirector?

Comment: Yes it would, but it will do that anyway! Only reason it alerts the right value is because the function is'nt bound in the handler, it's executed immediately because it has the paranthesis attached where it's suppose to be bound in `click`, so I don't really get what you're trying to do ?

Comment: trying to remove the target in the href and replace that with an onClick handler that could do other things and eventually redirect to what the user is trying to get to...